# After login attempt showing blank page not showing any error

Tags: php

**no error showing no login after attempt redirect to blank page**

i do not understand syntax error or ......

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $message = '';
    $error = '';
    //username and password sent from Form
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    
    if($email ==''){
        $error[] = '<p class="error">Please enter Email and Password.</p>';
    }
   
    else {
          $error[] = '<p class="error">Wrong Email and password.</p>';
      }    

    if($user->login($email,$password)){ 

        //logged in return to index page
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
        }      
    
    }//end if submit
if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
}
?>

<?php if(isset($message)){ echo $message; }?>
<form action="" method="post">  
<p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email " value=""  /></p>
<p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value=""  /></p>   
<p><label></label><input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Login"  /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: according to your code if login success then it will redirect to `index.php`. So what is the content you have on `index.php` and what is the browser url is after login?

Comment: my index page is nothing only welcome text but no error also showing

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page.

Comment: i can not understand how to show errors

Comment: <?php if(isset($message)){ echo $message; }?> replace with <?php if(isset($error)){ echo $error; }?> and try

Answer (score 0):

I guess like this you want? Because your question is so unclear, add more details

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $errors = '';

    //username and password sent from Form
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    
    if($email == '' || $password == ''){

        $errors[] = '<p class="error">Please enter Email and Password.</p>';
    }  

    if($user->login($email,$password)){ 

        //logged in return to index page
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    
    } else {

        $errors[] = '<p class="error">Wrong Email and password.</p>';
    }

    if(!empty($errors)){
        foreach($errors as $error){
            echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I paste this code but when i clicking submit button it going blank

Comment: ahhh now i know , the if statement in $user->login does not true because of that you got blank page

Comment: please fix for me

Comment: we can't fix that if your code provided is unclear, please add more details and provide your code

Comment: great man its working thank u very much blalalallla

Answer (score 0):

Your solution here!
`$error = array();`

You declare $error as a empty string. :))